# How to Increase a Timeout for an SSRS Report?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, timeout

I have an SSRS report running on our ASP.NET web application that reaches a run timeout after 15 minutes.
The following attributes shown in this article have been increased to more than 15 minutes:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23508.sql-server-reporting-services-troubleshooting-timeout-settings.aspx

Also, I have increased the SQL timeout to 120 minutes.
Still, a timeout is received after 15 minutes of the report running.

Comment: I'd recommend checking the performance of the report source first. Can you post the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but have you tried changing the "ProcessTimeout" option in the configuration file?
This option is disabled by default as stated in the Microsoft documentation:
[RsReportServer.config Configuration File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rsreportserver-config-configuration-file?view=sql-server-ver16)

The default location for the configuation file is usually under:

C:\Program Files\[Microsoft SQL ServerReportingServicesInstance]\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config